# What are these yearly spikes in the Russian Money Supply?

Tags: money-supply, money, demographics

During a school project, I realized there are these consistent annual spikes in the Russian money supply chart. Any one know what these are? [image]

https://tradingeconomics.com/russia/money-supply-m2

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at seasonally unadjusted data (M2 in blue below).

Intensity of supply and demand of credit fluctuates with seasons, and to allow analyzing the underlying trend, I suggest to download the seasonally adjusted data (M2_SA) from the [Bank of Russia (CBR) directly](https://www.cbr.ru/eng/search/?text=m2). The difference is like this:

[image]

CBR uses the standard [X-13ARIMA-SEATS Seasonal Adjustment Program](https://www.census.gov/data/software/x13as.html) from the US Census Bureau, in line with

- [ESS Guidelines on Seasonal Adjustment, Luxembourg: Office for Official Publications of the European Communities.](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/3859598/5910549/KS-RA-09-006-EN.PDF.pdf/0a9893a6-3e69-45c4-8328-6fc5a3497c13?t=1414781563000)
- [Monetary and Financial Statistics: Compilation Guide — Washington, D.C.: International Monetary Fund, 2008.](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/cgmfs/eng/pdf/cgmfs.pdf)

P.S. If you are interested in computer programming, you can try to compute this adjustment yourself, using some of the available packages (just google [X 13 Arima Seats Python](https://www.google.com/search?q=x13+arima+seats+python) for example).

Comment: @Pears, please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful.